# Dart-Polymer How to change app-drawer width

Tags: dart-polymer

How can I change the width of the Drawer in Polymer's App-drawer? There is the method getWidth, but no setWidth.

Do I need to use --app-drawer-width? If so, how is that done? I've tried this:

```
int drawerWidthPxInt = 256;

@Listen("handleNarrower")
handleNarrower(var event, var x) {
  AppDrawer drawer = document.querySelector("#idDrawerNav");
  drawerWidthPxInt -= 40;
  drawerWidthPxInt = max(drawerWidthPxInt, 36);
  drawer.customStyle['--app-drawer-width'] =  drawerWidthPxInt;
  drawer.updateStyles();
}
```

But that fails on the last line.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the width in the style section of your dom-module template, like below:

```
<template>
    <style>
        app-drawer {
            --app-drawer-width: 160px;
        }
        ...
    </style>
</template>
```